# Автодополнение в Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

Очень понравилось автодополнение в Inteliji Idea, но пересел работать за NetBeans и очень огорчён тем, что там автодополнение хуже, чем в Inteliji. Существует ли какой-нибудь плагин для автодополнения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Советую поизучать настройки, там есть всё, что может быть необходимо. Вы сами можете создавать необходимые шаблоны, которые будут вставляться после нажатия Tab.

Путь к настройкам шаблонов:

Сервис - Параметры (в самом низу) - Редактор - Шаблоны Кода

Если вам надо просто дополнять имена переменных и т. д., жать Ctrl + Пробел